# How to get boolean return from this sqlrunner function?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, boolean, return-value

Hopefully you can see a bit from the code what I'm trying to do here, basically I need to check if a record exists in a database, so I call a function to do so, but I'm using the sqlrunner class wherein the result of a query is called as an event response and I don't know how to get that value out of the resulting function back to the parent.
I feel like I must be doing things backwards or something..

```
        public function dbmatch(datetime:String, typecode:String):Boolean {
            var q:String = "SELECT DateTime FROM Event WHERE DateTime='"+datetime+"' AND EventTypeCode='"+typecode+"'"
            SQLService.getInstance().execute(q,null,matchresult);
            function matchresult(result:SQLResult):Boolean{
                var match:String = result.data[0];
                if (match == null){return false} else {return true}
            }
            return matchresult();
        }
```

elsewhere:

```
var recordexists:Boolean = dbmatch(datetime, "Gb");

if (!recordexists){...}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it always returning true?

Comment: @EyeSeeEm what i have there doesn't actually pull the return form matchresult.. it needs an argument, but i don't know how to put it. the main problem is that matchresult is initially called by an event listener and i don't know where its return goes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I think you need to change the program flow. The result can't be returned immediatly, so you will need to wait (i.e. listen) for it to finish, and then continue execution. If you need it, I could try and write an example, though I'm not sure it will work for your case, but it might help clarify things.

Comment: Do I need it to send it's own custom event?  I keep on running into this type of situation and I wonder if I'm sort of going about things in the wrong way. I just need to run a query to check if something exists, but the sqlrunner class only seems to work with resulthandlers, so i don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is that the SQLService class can't immediatly return a result for your query. That is why it uses a callback listener function (matchresult in your example) to inform your program at a later time that it has finished the search.

A basic way of handling this would be to call the query, then wait for the Query to "callback" to your listening funciton, that can then continue execution.

```
public function dbmatch(datetime:String, typecode:String, callbackListener:Function):void {
    var q:String = "SELECT DateTime FROM Event WHERE DateTime='"+datetime+"' AND EventTypeCode='"+typecode+"'"
    SQLService.getInstance().execute(q, null, callbackListener);
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
    // Start the query, but can't react to it immediatly        
    dbmatch(datetime, "Gb", onSQLQueryResult);

    // Your callback function
    public function onSQLQueryResult(result:SQLResult):void {
        var match:String = result.data[0];
        if (match == null) {
            // Do stuff you were going to do at (!recordexists)
        }
    }
```

Comment: callback function is new to me.. this looks like it should work.. however, the callback function is not being called..

Comment: it also says '3590: void used where a Boolean value was expected.  The expression will be type coerced to Boolean.'  on the 'dbmatch(datetime, "GB".. line

Comment: @damon did you change the dbmatch function's return type to void? Or are you still trying to assign the function's return value to your recordexists variable? That will no longer work, as dbmatch doesn't return anything anymore, it only initializes the SQL query.

Comment: i wonder if it is because my onSQLQuery Result function is inside another function (its there because values it needs are looping through in a forloop and then executing when it's finished.. and i can't easily take it out since then I'd need to pass arguments to onBgCheckResult..

Comment: (yeah everything is void right now as per the code you posted)

Comment: Hm, I don't think it should be a problem that the function is in another class, as the function is public and should be accessible by SQLService. Have you tried using a function inside the same class as the listener? Maybe add a trace right at the start of the callback function to be sure if it's being called or not. If it doesn't work I would need to see more of SQLService to be of any help.

Comment: i put a trace right at the beginning of the callback function, is how i concluded it wasn't running.. and currently everything is inside the same class.  this is all the code (needs to be broken up somehow at some point..) http://pastebin.com/xYkmqaYZ and sqlrunner code is here if you are interested in looking more http://bit.ly/hRU0m0

Comment: I think the function can't be inlined, it has to be a seperate function. Try this just to see if SQLService is actually returning something: http://pastebin.com/qC08nSYW If so, you will need to rethink the program flow. Your callback function will need to be where the actual reaction to the query is done, the interpret function will only be able to send off the request and not react.

Comment: yeah it works outside.. damn. will have to figure something else out though because i need the variables from the loop. thanks a lot though; callback functions could be pretty useful.